# Find common grouped sequence of items from lists in java

Tags: java, list, collections, sequence

I am trying to find the common grouped sequence of elements from multiple lists. I need help in implementing this in Java.

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("a");
a.add("b");
a.add("c");
a.add("d");
a.add("e");
a.add("f");
a.add("g");

List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
b.add("a");
b.add("b");
b.add("c");
b.add("d");
b.add("f");
b.add("g");

List<String> c = new ArrayList<String>();
c.add("h");
c.add("i");
c.add("a");
c.add("b");
c.add("c");
c.add("h");
c.add("i");
```

I expect the output of the common sequenced groups as ...

```
abc (repeated group in all 3 lists)
fg (repeated group in 2 lists)
d 
e
hi (repeated group in 2 lists)
```

I have tried multiple ways, but have not found a good solution yet.

Comment: Show us the multiple ways, and we might help you help to get the errors out of it.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried. This site is good at helping you improve your code but not good at doing the work for you.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/computing-common-and-unique                               trying to do this way , but it can give only one set of common elements not multiple sets